# Customizing android layout with bottom bar?

Tags: java, android-studio, android-layout, android-drawable, android-navigation-bar

I am new android studio.

The bottom bar overlaps on the page (Scrolling bar activity).
How to reduce the height of activity upto start of bottom bar?
Like ,The page must be inside the NavBar and Bottom, it should not exceed.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"

This works for me.